# How can I get the longest string that contains the most occurrences of a character in a list

Tags: c#, string, linq

This is my list:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>
{
   "Door Hardware > Door Trim",
   "Door Hardware > Door Trim > Pulls",
   "Door Hardware > Door Trim > Pulls > Flush",
   "Barn Doors & Hardware",
   "Barn Doors & Hardware > Barn Door Hardware",
   "Door Hardware",
   "Brands > Beyerle"
};
```

The value that I would need from the list is `"Door Hardware > Door Trim > Pulls > Flush"` which is the longest string that contains the greatest number of `'>'`.

This is what I have so far using LINQ:

```
var myVal = list.Where(s => s.Contains('>')).OrderByDescending(s => s.Length).First();
```

Which would return `"Barn Doors & Hardware > Barn Door Hardware"` which is not what I need.
I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: "which is the longest string that contains the greatest number of '>'" is ambigous. Do you mean "Find the string that has the most number of target characters" or "Find the string with the largest length with at least one target character" or "Find the strings that have the most number of target characters from the pool of input strings, then from the results, find the string that is the longest length"?

Comment: Instead of ordering by `s.Length`, which is the entire length of the string, order by `s.Count(x => x == '>')` which will count the `>` characters in the string.

Comment: It would be the last one. "Find the strings that contain the greatest number of the target character from the list of strings, then from the results, find the one with the longest length."

Comment: What if you have "aaBaaBaa" and "acBacBac" with a target character "B"? Which one should be returned? They both have the same string length and number of target characters.

Comment: @gunr2171 Either one could be returned. If those two were in a list, then I would just do 'list.First()'. The point is to narrow down which is the longest and has most '>' if two meet that criteria either one can be returned.

Comment: If you want to get occurence of specific sign, you need to split string on that sign, Then, you need to count it ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is that you need two levels of ordering.

1. Order by the number of target characters, descending.
2. (then) Order by the length of the string, descending.

```
char target = '>';
string selected = list
    .OrderByDescending(entry => entry.Count(letter => letter == target))
    .ThenByDescending(entry => entry.Length)
    .First();
```

Important here that you use `ThenBy...`, which "*appends*" to the existing ordering rather than overwriting the existing ordering.

Now, you'll still have the problem where multiple inputs could have the same number of target characters and string length. Right now (with both this code and your code), it will choose the first based on the order from the original list. You may want to change that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `List.Sort`.
This would look like that:

```cs
list.Sort((x, y) => { return x.Count(s => s == '>') == y.Count(s => s == '>') ? x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length) : x.Count(s => s == '>').CompareTo(y.Count(s => s == '>')); });
```

All I'm doing here is:
Checking if the count of ">" occurrences is equal

if yes, sort by length

if no sort by the count of ">" occurrences.

From that list, the last element would be your result.